# Injecting a hook DLL into a process before its imports get called?

Tags: c++, process, hook, dll-injection, detours

I have a target process which loads a DLL before its main code gets called. It accomplishes this through a DLL whose name was added to the file's ImportsTable (using StudPE). My goal is to create a hook DLL that will be injected into this process and intercept its calls before it loads its imports. So the target process will load my hook dll before its security DLL. I tried using the conventional method but I hadn't success because the security DLL always gets called before my hook DLL's DllMain is called. Can anybody tell me a method to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the target process suspended and use CreateRemoteThread() for injection, but mind the following limitations:

1. You should copy the thread main routine for the remote thread to the address space of the target process.
2. This code cannot contain any external references (e.g. CRTL or direct WinApi calls). I would usually limit this code to loading of the DLL and either executing function from it, or relying on the DllMain to do the job you need. In order to call LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress methods, I obtain their addresses and copy structure containing this information to the target process and pass the address of the remote structure as an argument for the thread main routine in CreateRemoteThread(). You can use VirtualAllocEx() to allocate memory in the remote process.
3. Remote thread in this situation will be executed before main thread, including process and some Win32/64 initialization. Therefore, not every Win32 API is safe to call in this condition.

If the target process is spawned by someone else, you have to intercept its creation before it is initialized. There are some ways to do that, all of them are undocumented and therefore not future proof.

Answer (score 0):

The DLL are loaded sequentially in the same order as the imports entries in the PE header. Most PE editors will let you reorder the imports. You should also note that if another DLL X has dependencies on the security DLL, then it will be loaded at the same time as DLL X. Also, if security DLL is using static loading, hooking by modifying the import tables at runtime should still be effective even if your DLL is loaded later, though you will miss the calls done in the meantime (but there shouldn't be any).